# Rally C#: How to attach a feature to an user story?

Tags: c#, api, rally

I am trying to add a feature while I create a user story. Here is my sample code below. I was wondering if this will work.

```
DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toCreate[RallyConstant.Name] = usName;
toCreate[RallyConstant.WorkSpace] = usWorkspace;
toCreate[RallyConstant.Project] = usProject;
toCreate[RallyConstant.Iteration] = usIteration;
toCreate["Feature"] = "testFeature";

CreateResult cr = _api.Create("HierarchicalRequirement", toCreate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Feature attribute is readonly.  You should use PortfolioItem:

```
toCreate["PortfolioItem"] = "/portfolioitem/feature/12345";
```